# Async Validator for unique name

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, asynchronous, angular-material

I want know if it's possible to make a submit to a server before submit the form.

I explain you, I have a form with some input, these input ( ex: name, group, client ) may have already create but I need to make a request to server when I live the input field for have an answer and display a error message.

I made a custon async Validator but something is wrong,
I just want to check if the name already exist but it may also leave blank.

Now when I use it , it always show me error validation .

```
import {AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, AsyncValidatorFn} from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable} from "rxjs";
import {FixtureService} from "../../app/services/fixture.service";
import {map} from'rxjs/operators';

export function UniqueFixtureNameValidator(fixtureService: FixtureService): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (c: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
    return fixtureService.getFixture(c.value).pipe(
      map(name => {
       return name && name.length > 0 ? { 'uniqueFixtureName': true } : null;
      })
    );
  };
}
```

Comment: [Async Validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#async-validation) may be something to look into for this.

Comment: is it easy to use it ?

Comment: It is very easy to use.. [link](https://alligator.io/angular/async-validators/)

Comment: I edit my code with my custom async validator who's non working like I want

Comment: please provide a [mcve], how are you using this validator?